Probability/Standard Normal Distribution Homework Help
I am so stuck on this problem in my homework, and was wondering if someone could offer any tips on how to approach it?


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Three hints:

What is the distribution of the mean of a normal variable?
What is the variance of this mean? Aka standard error
Check the 97.5 percentile for a normal distribution

Btw, do not use Chebyshev's inequality; a) it will not give you the answer b) it does make use of the fact that the X variable is normally distributed (the inequality is for any distribution).

When we have iid normal random variables with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$, the sample mean is also a normal random variable, with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$$/$$n$.
You can then standardize the sample mean to get another standard normal.  Then use this to find the smallest $n$ for which the above probability holds.

If $X_i$'s are iid standard normal, then $\bar{X}$ also follows  normal distribution with mean 0 and standard deviation $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}.$
For a random variable $X$, if the population mean is denoted by $\mu$ and the population standard deviation is denoted by $\sigma$, then for any real number $k>0$, Chebyshev's inequality states that
$$\mathbb{P}(\mu-k\sigma<X<\mu+k\sigma)\geq 1-\frac{1}{k^2}.$$
Match the following inequality with the given probability expression and solve this for $n:$
$$\mathbb{P}\left(-\frac{k}{\sqrt{n}}<\bar{X}<\frac{k}{\sqrt{n}}\right)\geq 1-\frac{1}{k^2}=0.95.$$
EDIT:
As @jginestet pointed out, Chebyshev's inequality won't give the proper answer here as it only indicates the minimum lower bound for any random variable with finite mean and variance. As we already know the distribution of the random variable $\bar{X}$ it is better to use that fact. Since $\bar{X}$ follows a normal distribution with mean 0 and standard deviation $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$, using the empirical rule of normal distribution, we can get
$$\mathbb{P}\left(-\frac{2}{\sqrt{n}}<\bar{X}<\frac{2}{\sqrt{n}}\right)\approx 0.95.$$
Solving this for $n$ will give the sample size.

I don't know how you arrived at this inequality, but once you obtain $k$, the calculations are pretty much straightforward. any $n$ satisfying the given inequality shall give the minimum sample size.

Thank you. Can you show how to solve for $n$?

The post asked for hints. Actually solving it would clearly run into the rule relating to  homework / self study questions

Are you able to consider solving this? I already turned in the homework and didn't get points for this. Just want to learn because I really am stuck in this unit.
